# AWS SNS implement on laravel-4

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sns

I am implementing AWS SNS on my project, I am trying to send push notification to Android and iOS device using AWS SNS service, but I am not getting proper document to implement step by step.

My code is as follows

```
     $aws = Aws::factory(array(
            'profile' => 'my_profile',
            'region'  => 'us-east-1',
            'key'   =>  Config::get('app.aws_access_key'),
            'secret'    =>Config::get('app.aws_secret_access_key')
        ));

   $this->sns = $aws->get('Sns');

   $task = $this->sns->publish(
            array(
                'TargetArn' => 'arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:341707006110:My-topic',
                'Message' => 'Hello from PHP',
                'Subject' => 'Hello world!'
            ));
```

I am getting the following error:

> User: arn:aws:iam::341707006110:user/my-topic is not authorized to perform

I have a device token like "APA91bGUAbXanTXExEtDpr9XfZE8leNJtB3V" and I want to send push notification on this device. How can I pass device token to publish() method?

Comment: Can you give complete error stack?

Answer (score 0):

Basically, the issue raises from the fact that your Topic/Target arn is for us-west-2. But by default your SNS client is pointing to us-east-1. You need to call setRegion on snsClient.

Try after updating the region.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your IAM role doesn't have SNS permissions. Try adding them and then try this.
In AWS web console goto IAM -> Roles -> select your role -> Attach Policy -> filter using keywords `sns`, and attach the appropriate policy.